# problem loading images asynchronously

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronization, handler

I have an application that uses images from web a a source. for my application I'm first downloading images in seperate thread and only if image exists on disk I show on the list. Downloader is a seperate thread, but  I'm very new using threads and now something else is confusing me. My images are not shown unless I refresh the view, that is my list. Now I needed to show my images so I wrote this in my custom view :

```
private  Runnable LoaderTask=new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        if(cellIcon!=null){
            if(iconCache.get(cellIcon)!=null){              
                icon.setImageBitmap(iconCache.get(cellIcon)); 
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);
            }
        }

    }

};
private class ImageThread extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //  mHandler.removeCallbacks(LoaderTask);
          mHandler.postDelayed(LoaderTask, 100);


    }

}
```

And I trigger my thread like this

```
  ImageThread thread=new ImageThread();
    thread.start();
```

the handler is instantiated in the beginning of the class. But when I do this n othing happen until I refresh my views. I tried (Activity).runOnUIThread inside one of my threads I got stackoverflow error. How do I solve that or are there any other advices.you can give me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AsyncTask. In onPostExecute() method just call a method from the activity and refresh the UI. The onPostExecute() is called when the thread is done.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

P.S. To call an activity's method just use Interface.

Comment: Hi Pepi, Thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot but still no async loading images. I tried this `code` private class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String,Bitmap>,Void,Bitmap>{

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
   icon.setImageBitmap(result);
  }


  @Override
  protected Bitmap doInBackground(HashMap<String, Bitmap>... params) {
    return model.getIconCache().get(cellIcon);   
  }
  
 } `code`   but I m getting the same thing. icon cache is loading by time I need a task to periodically check the cache and if sees an item

Comment: to periodically check, use AlarmManager that runs your task periodically

Comment: Hmm, actually I don't know how to use AlarmManager too, but I will check it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html